# How to install GIMP on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, gimp

I was looking for any alternatives to Adobe Photoshop to install on my laptop. I downloaded GIMP but could not install on my Windows 7 (64 bit).

It says this file is corrupt. Is there no version available for Windows 7?

Any suggestions or alternatives?

Answer (score 6):

Gimp certainly works for Windows 7x64(I use it often), I would recommend re-downloading and installing again.

Answer (score 2):

[Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) is good and getting better all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The sourceforge page states it is compatible with Windows 7 64-bit:

> Operating System
>   32-bit MS Windows (NT/2000/XP), 64-bit MS Windows, Vista, Windows 7, WinXP

and there is [another post](https://superuser.com/questions/279361/gimp-2-6-11-on-windows-7-64-bit-cant-open-png-files) on SU from someone who says it works.

Try downloading from the official project page on [**sourceforge**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-win/) again and try with an alternative browser if you have continual problems with corrupt downloads.

Answer (score 0):

gimp may not meet PhotoShop 1:1 on all features, but it is 100% for my web developer and design needs. I stopped using PhotoShop YEARS ago; and I don't miss it, period. Have you tried http://gimp-win.sourceforge.net/stable.html for your download?